# Why I can't perform mouse move using Selenium WebDriver for C# and PageFactory in initialization

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have an link in HTML and I use Page Object pattern to write scripts with Selenium. But I can't perform MouseMove action when object is initialized with pageFactory.
So, I have such class:

```
class BingPage
{
private readonly IWebDriver driver;
public static readonly String BASE_URL = "http://bing.com/";
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = ".//*[@id='scpt2']/a[text()='Shopping']")]
private IWebElement ShoopingLink;

public BingPage(IWebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    //Page Factory will use Driver to init searchButton and queryEdit objects
    PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
}

public void HoverShoppingLink()
{
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='scpt2']/a[text()='Shopping']"));
    builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();//This will work

    builder.MoveToElement(ShoopingLink).Build().Perform(); //This will fail
}
}
```

Line marked with comment "This will fail" will throw an exception "Must provide a location for a move action. Parameter name: actionTarget"

But when I manually lookup element - it works.
Could someone tell me why?

It is selenium 2.0 for .Net, .Net 4.0 with IE driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the proxy object (`ProxiedWebElementInterceptor`) created for the element doesn't proxy `ILocatable`, which is what the `Actions` class requires of its methods. This is a bug in the .NET bindings. It has been fixed in the current sources, and will be available in the next public release (2.21), available soon.

Comment: it reproduces again in 2.48.2 version. Now the error is Object does not match target type