# How to use mouse events in c# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, mouse

I'm trying to test mouse events in selenium.

Here's what I tried:

```
        Actions builder = new Actions(d);

        IWebElement elem = d.FindElementById("gbqfq");
        builder.MoveToElement(elem).Build().Perform();
```

No effect, the mouse does not move.

The other option would be to use `d.Mouse.MouseMove();` but I can't find a way to convert `IWebElement` to `ICoordinates` which this method accepts.

Can anyone point me to a good example how to work with mouse in selenium?

What I want to accomplish is to move mouse over the center of a web element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974488/selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point | http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074904/why-i-cant-perform-mouse-move-using-selenium-webdriver-for-c-sharp-and-pagefact

Comment: I've tried converting IWebElement to ICoordinates. It throws up on in my face

Comment: If you're expecting the physical mouse cursor to move with your WebDriver code, you're going to be disappointed. WebDriver does not move the physical mouse cursor. Using the `Actions` class is the correct way to proceed, but without the context of what page you're executing against, it'll be very hard to provide you with more specific advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you browser is selected or in other word your browser should be at active stated on the top of the screen.  You can achieve that by maximizing the window. 
You can refer follwing article for this.
http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/mouse-hover-and-other-mouse-events-in-webdriver/